# Exporting names of "legend column" to spreadsheet (and not value) using QGIS

Tags: qgis, export, legend, spreadsheet

I want to export a layer to spreadsheet but need the name in the "legend" column (see pic).

Does anyone have a solution for this?

When I use the tool "**export to spreadsheet**", it's exporting the "value" column.
The same happens when I use "**Save features as ...**"
I don't need the symbology in excel. Only those legend names.

I know I could re-name the different lines, so the value name and the legend name are the same.
But then my features disappear and I'd need to re-assign them to the new value.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing up legend and data. You can not export data and change datavalues during that process. You could either change your data before exporting or, my suggestion here, create a new temporary layer with modified data and export this layer as an excel sheet.

1. Search for "Refactor fields" in processing toolbox

[image: List item]

2. Find the field you want to change the data and click the expression button. Leave the other fields as they are.

[image]

3. Enter the expression `if("name"='1.5 Sonstiger Forst','1.5 Sonstiger Forst (Vorwald)',"name")`. That means if the value of the name field is *1.5 Sonstiger Forst*, then change it, otherwise take the value that is already stored.
4. Now choose your output file and save it as xlsx

[image]

Comment: First: Thanks for the hint with the "refactor fields", never used it, but it's certainly helpful for some tasks.

The thing is: I start digitizing the whole project and then go in the properties and change the legend names, and those are not always the same. So your "IF..." expression won't work as intended.
I saw another post about a python code that exports the legend from the composer with symbology. Maybe that's the only way. I just hoped there would be an elegant way with build-in tools without coding.

Comment: I just realized, I also need the area field of my layer, so the approach with exporting the legend from the composer won't work either, I guess.

Comment: You are still mixing up the differences between legend and data ;) Sounds like you need to clean up your data. You can use case when and like expressions with wildcards for more cases.

Comment: Hm, I do realize, that even though I select a type of vegetation in the dropdown, I see the legend name but actually assign the "value" to the feature, right? But is there a way to automatically update all "values" with the "legend name". Is there an expression for that legend name? That data has to be somewhere, doesn't it?

Comment: I dont think there is an expression to access it. Probably doable via PyQGIS. Or extractable from the .qml file. However, I'd just create a lookup table containing value -> legend or vice versa as CSV, then you can update your data easily.

Comment: That's an idea! Thanks a lot! Will try that!